# Pick which Visual Studio to open old .sln-s with Visual Studio's Version Selector

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, visual-studio-2010

I have both Visual Studio 2008 and 2010 installed, side-by-side, and VSLauncher correctly opens 9.0 *.sln*-s with VS2008 and 10.0 *.sln*-s with VS2010.

However, whenever it encounters an older *.sln* (e.g. 8.0), VSLauncher automatically picks Visual Studio 2010.

For various reasons, I would like to choose which VS it should open to convert to, but it blindly opens VS2010. I see that there's *RMB > Open With > Microsoft Visual Studio Version Selector*, but this doesn't produce a list of installed *VS*-es that I'd anticipate, it simply launches VS2010.

Is there a way to get the configuration I'm looking for?

Background info:

- They were installed in chronological release order
- I'm running Windows 7 x64
- Both *VS*-es are 32-bit

Answer (score 0):

I think that the justification for this behavior is:

If you have an "older" project (say VS2005), then no matter which versino of VS you use to open the project, there is going to be a conversion process.

With that in mind, it makes sense to convert to the newest version available. Converting a VS2005 project to VS2010 isn't significantly harder than converting it to VS2008, but you'll have more capabilities once the conversion is complete.

Old versions of Microsoft products eventually don't get supported anymore... I think the policy is to fully support the last 2 versions, and then the previous version for 2 years (or is that 1 year). Not sure the date that VS2010 came out, but support for VS2005 will expire either 1 or 2 years after that... If you convert your VS2005 project to VS2008, you'll have the same pain all over again 1-2 years after the next version of VS comes out.

That said, the real answer to your question is: Get in the habit of opening .SLN files with Notepad, so that you can figure out what version it is. Then open up the correct version of VS and click on File/Open to open the project. It isn't as convenient as double-click, but once you get into the habit, it isn't all that bad.